# Echo an image inside the body text in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, echo

I want to put an image inside the body text of my WordPress homepage.

I used

```
printf( ' [<]img src="%s/_images/side2.png"[>]', bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'));
```

and also echo and what I get is something like **(localhost/esw/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elisium)** and(image) icon.

The text is the body text of the homepage, and I am trying to put this image through editor inside the WordPress.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: NO but the image is not showing, instead of the image I am getting the  localhostlink. I tried to use different images but still the results are the same.

Comment: is this hosted online ? is there some output we can see?

Comment: It is localhosting, as I have mentioned and no I tried to place screen shot but I am not allowed by the stackoerflow to do so .. 

the problem is not with the command i believe it is just the image is not showing .. 

I tried echo instead of printf still the same thing ..

Comment: you could take a screenshot and upload it to [imgur](http://imgur.com/)

Comment: I suppose what I don't quite understand is why you need to print/echo an image when you can just add it via the editor or some simple HTML direct linkage (img src etc.)?

Comment: I have edited the homepage/index manually instead of creating a page and making it index. 

Now I have all my theme setup, I would love to use html but I am not sure if I can embed in .php file or how to :)